# Implementation of binary heap in C++

Tags: c++, stl, heap

Things I can think of include integer overflow, if the input type is int, etc. But other than that, what do you think is wrong with this code, design-wise, style-wise, and also in terms of other edge/corner cases?

**binaryheap.h**

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_BINARYHEAP_H_
#define INCLUDE_BINARYHEAP_H_

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>

// Assume min heap
template <class T>
class BinaryHeap
{
 private:
  unsigned long heap_size_;
  std::vector<T> data_;
  // typedef typename std::vector<T>size_type heap_size_;
  void SiftUp(unsigned long node);
  void SiftDown(unsigned long node);

 public:
  BinaryHeap(unsigned long num_elements);
  BinaryHeap();
  ~BinaryHeap() {}

  // Misc Operations (using STL namimg).
  unsigned long count() { return heap_size_;}  // Get count of objects.
  void clear();                      // clear the object for reuse.

  // Main operations allowed by the data structure.
  template <class I>
  int Heapify(I start, I end);
  const T FindXtrma();
  const T ExtractXtrma();
  void Insert(const T& data);   // Insert(key)
  void Delete(unsigned long element);     // Delete(element)
  void IncreaseKey(unsigned long element, const T& change);
  void DecreaseKey(unsigned long element, const T& change);
  unsigned long get_size(){return(heap_size_);}
  /* void Merge(class &Heap); */
};

#endif  // INCLUDE_BINARYHEAP_H_
```

**binaryheap.cpp**

```
#include <binaryheap.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
BinaryHeap<T>::BinaryHeap(unsigned long num_elements)
{ heap_size_ = num_elements;
  data_.reserve(num_elements);
}


template <class T>
BinaryHeap<T>::BinaryHeap()
{ heap_size_ = 0;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::SiftDown(unsigned long node)
{ unsigned long lchild = 2*node+1;
  unsigned long rchild = 2*node+2;

  bool rexists = rchild < heap_size_;
  bool lexists = lchild < heap_size_;
  if (!lexists && !rexists) return;
  bool left_small;
  if (rexists && data_[lchild] > data_[rchild])
    left_small = false;
  else
    left_small = true;

  if (data_[lchild] < data_[node] && left_small)
  { std::swap(data_[node], data_[lchild]);
    SiftDown(lchild);
  }
  else if (data_[rchild] < data_[node] && rexists && !left_small)
  { std::swap(data_[node], data_[rchild]);
    SiftDown(rchild);
  }
}

template <class T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::SiftUp(unsigned long node)
{ long parent = floor(node/2)-(node+1)%2;
  bool pexists = parent >= 0;
  if (pexists && data_[parent] > data_[node])
  { std::swap(data_[parent], data_[node]);
    SiftUp(parent);
  }
}

template <class T>
template <class I>
int BinaryHeap<T>::Heapify(I start, I end)
{ unsigned long d = std::distance(start, end);
  if (data_.size() != 0)
    this->clear();
  if (heap_size_ == 0)
    heap_size_ = d;
  // may be warn them.
  if (d != heap_size_)
    heap_size_ = d;
  for (I i = start; i != end; ++i)
    data_.push_back(*i);
  for (unsigned long i = heap_size_-1; i <= heap_size_; --i)
  { SiftDown(i);
  }
  return 0;
}

template <class T>
const T BinaryHeap<T>::FindXtrma()
{ if (heap_size_ <= 0)
    return ((T)(0));
  return data_.front();
  // return this->data_[0];
}

template <class T>
const T BinaryHeap<T>::ExtractXtrma()
{ if (heap_size_ <= 0)
    return ((T)(0));
  T max_value = data_.front();
  std::swap(data_.front(), data_.back());
  data_.pop_back();
  --heap_size_;
  SiftDown(0);
  return max_value;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::Insert(const T& new_node)
{ data_.push_back(new_node);
  SiftUp(data_.size()-1);
  ++heap_size_;
}

template <class T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::Delete(unsigned long element)
{ if (element >= heap_size_)
    return;
  std::swap(data_[element], data_.back());
  data_.pop_back();
  --heap_size_;
  SiftUp(element);
  SiftDown(element);
}

template <class T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::IncreaseKey(unsigned long element, const T& change)
{ data_[element] = data_[element]+change;
  SiftDown(element);
}

template <class T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::DecreaseKey(unsigned long element, const T& change)
{ data_[element] = data_[element]-change;
  SiftUp(element);
}

template <class T>
void BinaryHeap<T>::clear()
{ if (data_.size()  > 0)
    data_.clear();
}

template class BinaryHeap<int>;
template class BinaryHeap<float>;
template class BinaryHeap<unsigned int>;
template class BinaryHeap<long>;


template int BinaryHeap<int>::Heapify(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator);
template int BinaryHeap<float>::Heapify(std::vector<float>::iterator, std::vector<float>::iterator);
template int BinaryHeap<unsigned int>::Heapify(std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator, std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator);
template int BinaryHeap<long>::Heapify(std::vector<long>::iterator, std::vector<long>::iterator);
```

**binaryheap_gtest.cpp**

```
#include <binaryheap.h>
#include <vector>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

using namespace std;

namespace
{ template<class T>
  class BHeapTest : public ::testing::Test
  {
   public:
    BinaryHeap<T> b1;
    BHeapTest() { b1 = BinaryHeap<T>(1000);}
    virtual ~BHeapTest() {}

   protected:
    vector<T> data_;
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
      unsigned long max_val = 2000;
      for (T i = 1000; i < (T)max_val; ++i)
        data_.push_back(i);
      b1.Heapify(data_.begin(), data_.end());
    }
    virtual void TearDown()
    { data_.clear();
    }
  };

  typedef ::testing::Types<int, unsigned int, long> MyTypes;
  TYPED_TEST_CASE(BHeapTest, MyTypes);

  TYPED_TEST(BHeapTest, SimpleTest)
  { EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.get_size());
    this->b1.Insert(3000);
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(1001, this->b1.get_size());
    this->b1.Delete(0);
    EXPECT_EQ(1001, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.get_size());
    this->b1.DecreaseKey(999, 1000);
    EXPECT_EQ(999, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.get_size());
    this->b1.IncreaseKey(0,1000);
    EXPECT_EQ(1001, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.get_size());
  }

  TYPED_TEST(BHeapTest, ComplexTest)
  { EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, this->b1.get_size());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      this->b1.ExtractXtrma();
    EXPECT_EQ(1010, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(990, this->b1.get_size());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      this->b1.ExtractXtrma();
    EXPECT_EQ(1020, this->b1.FindXtrma());
    EXPECT_EQ(980, this->b1.get_size());
    this->b1.Insert(3232);
    EXPECT_EQ(981, this->b1.get_size());
  }
}  //  namespace

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you seem to be tryingy to mimic the style of STL containers (at least, that's what your comments say), there are several things you could improve:

### STL containers subtypes

Most of the STL containers have subtypes. I am pretty sure that some parts of the standard library use these subtypes. Therefore, if you want your code to work with the generic algorithms, you better add those subtypes:

- `value_type`: probably be an alias for `T`, or `std::vector<T>::value_type`.
- `size_type`: in your case, it would be `unsigned long` since it is the type you use for the size of your heap. Generally, the type `std::size_t` is used for `size_type` though. The best solution in your case would be `std::vector<T>::size_type`
- `reference`: often `T&`.
- There are many other subtypes. Look at [the documentation for `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and see which one you can take from the underlying `std::vector` and which one you better let alone (for example, you don't provide anything to work with iterators and you don't provide any mechanism for allocators).

### Size of the heap

First of all, you have two functions to obtain the size of your heap, `count` and `get_size`, which is redundant. `count` is there so that your heap looks like an STL container, however, the standard method name to get the size of a container is `size`, not `count`. There is no need for the function `get_size`: it is a duplicate, it does not conform to STL naming, and it does not even conform to the case of your other functions.

I find the fact that the size of your heap does not correspond to the size of the underlying `std::vector` rather troubling. When I write this:

```
BinaryHeap<int> foo(8);
```

I know that enough memory has been reserved for 8 elements, but I would expect the size to be 0. Moreover, if I write this:

```
BinaryHeap<int> foo(8);
foo.FindXtrma();
```

I then have no idea what my value will be since the size is 8 and I did not control the inserted values. Generally speaking, you probably should implement `size` like this to avoid surprises:

```
size_type size() const
{
    return data_.size();
}
```

There are probably other things which could be improved: make your `BinaryHeap` more like a STL container by enabling a support for allocators for example (you could forward the allocator stuff directly to the underlying `std::vector` to avoid having to actually handle them). Also, instead of a real container, you could try to make your `BinaryHeap` a container adapter (like `std::stack` or `std::queue`) so that it can use an `std::vector` or an `std::deque` (or any conforming container).

### Miscellaneous C++ stuff

*It has been more than a year since the review, but it seems that it has some views, so I thought that it could be a good idea to complete it with some miscellaneous additional comments...*

- You have template code in a `.cpp` file, this is really error-prone since templates are not compiled (their specializations are instantiated and compiled when needed). If you want to write a template library with separate interface and implementation, then put the interface in a `.h` file and include a `.inl` or `.tpp` file at the end of the header (these are the most common extensions for "implementation header files") with the implementation.
- You should `const`-qualify functions that do not alter the state of the class. For example, `count` (or `size` as I mentioned before) does not alter the heap and can be `const`-qualified to document that.
- Sometimes, your names should be more explicit. For example, `template <class I>` isn't explicit enough. It is easy to guess that it accepts iterators, but which kind of iterators? From the implementation, I think that it can accept [forward iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator), so you should use names which reflect that fact:

  ```
  template <class ForwardIterator>
  int Heapify(ForwardIterator start, ForwardIterator end);
  ```
- By the way, this function does not return anything useful, it always return `0`, which is at best useless and at worst confusing (and undocumented). The best thing to do is to make your function return `void` so that it is clear that it isn't returning anything:

  ```
  template <class ForwardIterator>
  void Heapify(ForwardIterator start, ForwardIterator end);
  ```
- You can replace this loop:

  ```
  for (I i = start; i != end; ++i)
      data_.push_back(*i);
  ```

  ...by a call to [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) from the standard header `<algorithm>` with [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to automatically perform the calls to `push_back` on the `data_`.

  ```
  std::copy(start, end, std::back_inserter(data_));
  ```
- Whenever possible, try to initialize what you can into a constructor initialization list instead of initializing things in the constructor body. Take for example this constructor:

  ```
  template <class T>
  BinaryHeap<T>::BinaryHeap(unsigned long num_elements)
  { heap_size_ = num_elements;
    data_.reserve(num_elements);
  }
  ```

  It is trivial to initialize `heap_size_` from the initialization list, and feeding an integer to an `std::vector` constructor will actually be equivalent to a call to `reserve`. That means that you can write this constructor as:

  ```
  template <class T>
  BinaryHeap<T>::BinaryHeap(unsigned long num_elements):
      heap_size_(num_elements),
      data_(num_elements)
  {}
  ```
- This boolean initialization looks rather complicated:

  ```
  bool left_small;
  if (rexists && data_[lchild] > data_[rchild])
    left_small = false;
  else
    left_small = true;
  ```

  You can make a one-liner out of it which shouldn't be harder to read:

  ```
  bool left_small = !(rexists && data_[lchild] > data_[rchild]);
  ```

  You can even change it a little bit to remove the leading `operator!`:

  ```
  bool left_small = !rexists || data_[lchild] <= data_[rchild];
  ```

Comment: Mimicking style of STL containers : I was not exactly intending that you thought. I was following Google Style Guide and the naming convention for getter and setter functions (or other simple functions) was an exception to their rule, and I was following the STL style naming. But your suggestion is a welcome change. Thanks for the nice review, will incorporate most of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in the code:

```
if (data_[rchild] < data_[node] && rexists && !left_small)
```

You have to check `rexists` before `data_[rchild]`:

```
if (rexists && !left_small && data_[rchild] < data_[node])
```